# Sync local test server with local git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

what is the best approach to sync local test server with local git repository.

My company develops rails project which is hosted on GitHub. We have a build server (Jenkins) which is triggered every time when a pull request is opened. Running all tests takes significant time, so I would like to setup my own local test server which will run against my local git repository. 
My development machine is a laptop and the test server is powerful desktop machine which I don't use.

Thanks